# Test.MainForm.Dispose(bool): no ​suitable method to override (CS0115)

Tags: c#

I am coding a C# Form Application. The following code is my 'MainForm.cs'.

```
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsChromium
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

    public void InitBrowser()
    {
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com");
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        browser.LoadingStateChanged += browser_LoadingStateChanged; 
    }

    private void browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsLoading == false)
        {
            browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("alert('All Resources Have Loaded');");
        }
    }

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitBrowser();
    }
}
}
```

There is no problem with that file. I am having a problem with my 'MainForm.Designer.cs'. The following code is that file.

```
namespace Test
{
partial class MainForm
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) {
            if (components != null) {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(534, 279);
        this.Name = "MainForm";
        this.Text = "Test";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
}
}
```

The error is "Test.MainForm.Dispose(bool): no ​​suitable method to override (CS0115)". I think the problem is the 'protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)'. How can i fix it?

Comment: Did you make components inherit IDisposable?

Comment: @yaakov : The component class needs to be IDisposable.

Comment: how do i do it?

Comment: IContainer is [also disposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icontainer?view=netframework-4.8), and in any event, would yield a different compiler error than the OP's if it was not.

Comment: Happens when the Form declaration in the foo.designer.cs file gets out of sync with the foo.cs file.  In this case it is the namespace name.  You avoid it by right-clicking the identifier name and picking Rename.  The IDE is smart enough to change it everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in different namespaces

You have namespace `WinFormsChromium` for the .cs file and `Test` in the Designer.cs file

Please replace `namespace Test` with `namespace WinFormsChromium` in the .Designer.cs file to make `partial class MainForm` parts visible to each other

Comment: The `.Designer` is generated automatically. There is no point in editing it.

Comment: @GSerg you are right but seems that MainForm.cs namespace was changed from `Test` to `WinFormsChromium` (just look on the source code). Namespace must be the same to make partial class parts visible to each other

Comment: Yes, it must be the same, but the change has to be made in the other file, or probably in the "Default namespace" setting in the project.

Comment: @GSerg `Default namespace` option does not change the existing namespaces. I've made a lot of changes in the `.Designer.cs` files when namespace is changing in the related `.cs` file